# use sed to update Dockerfile version label

Tags: bash, sed

i have the following shell script:

```
SHELL += -eu

VERSION :=$$(./version.sh)


deploy:
    sed -i '/version=/s/".*"/"${VERSION}"/' Dockerfile
```

but i get this error:

```
sed -i '/version=/s/".*"/"$(./version.sh)"/' Dockerfile
sed: -e expression #1, char 23: unknown option to `s'
```

version.sh

```
jq -rM '.version' package.json
```

What am I missing?

Any advice is much appreciated

Comment: i think you should use the 's' command in sed: sed -i 's/version=/s....'

Comment: @RigaCrypto no, in this case, OP is using `filter+s command` so that the `s` command will apply only if line contains `version=`

Comment: either turn on shell debugging with `set -x` (turn off with `set +x`) and see what values are being used inside of the `sed "....strings..."` or run `version.sh` on cmd-line, take the value returned, and manally execute the `sed` command to see if that works. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

thanks for the advice, this is what works

```
sed -i '/version=/s/".*"/\"'$$(./version.sh)'"/' Dockerfile
```

or

```
SHELL += -eu

VERSION :=$$(./version.sh)
sed -i '/version=/s/".*"/\"'${VERSION}'"/' Dockerfile
```

i needed to put the `$$(./version.sh)` in single quotes